# PHPExcel how to set cell value dynamically using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't fix what's wrong in my code. It results to ONE data. what i need is to loop and get all the data from the database using this lines.

Controller

```
function firstDebit(){
$series=$this->uri->segment(3); 

$this->db->select ( 'accountcode.accountName' );
$this->db->from ( 'accountcode' );
$this->db->join ( 'generalaccount ', 'generalaccount.AccountCode = accountcode.id');
$this->db->where ( 'generalaccount.Series', $series);
$this->db->where ( 'generalaccount.Account', 'debit');
$this->db->where ( 'generalaccount.Count', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->row_array();

$rowNumber=10;

foreach($query->row_array() as $rows){
     $this->excel->setCellValue('b'.$rowNumber, $rows);
     $rowNumber++;

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is result_array so your code would be

```
function firstDebit(){
    $series=$this->uri->segment(3); 

    $this->db->select ( 'accountcode.accountName' );
    $this->db->from ( 'accountcode' );
    $this->db->join ( 'generalaccount ', 'generalaccount.AccountCode = accountcode.id');
    $this->db->where ( 'generalaccount.Series', $series);
    $this->db->where ( 'generalaccount.Account', 'debit');
    $this->db->where ( 'generalaccount.Count', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $rowNumber=10;

    foreach($query->result_array() as $rows){
         $this->excel->setCellValue('b'.$rowNumber, $rows['accountName']);
         $rowNumber++;

    }
}
```

Comment: i used it Folio but it produces an error.
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: Cell/DefaultValueBinder.php

Line Number: 82

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\acc\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php
Line: 82
Function: _error_handler

Comment: as a result of using result array you must using $rows['accountName'] as a cell value.